# How to create a chooser for fragments in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 Fragments say FragmentA, FragmentB and FragmentC. I have a button on FragmentA. I want a chooser to be opened as when click on the button of FragmentA which will all the user to choose from FragmentB and FragmentC.

By chooser I mean like a `intent.createChooser()` which gives options to the user to choose a intent from the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Fragment`s should always be designed for reuse, and hence, you should not write code that directly references a `Fragment` from another `Fragment`. In other words, the parent `ActivityA` should manage your Fragment transactions for you.

Let's assume that `ActivityA` is the parent Activity for `FragmentA`, `FragmentB`, and `FragmentC`. What you could do is define a callback interface inside the fragment and require that the host activity implement it. When the activity receives a callback through the interface, it can share the information with other fragments in the layout as necessary. If you are only ever dealing with one parent Activity to manage all three `Fragments`, you won't need to create new `Intents` to start new `Activity`s... instead, your parent `ActivityA` should make use of the `FragmentManager` and simply fill its layout with the desired fragment when an event callback is received.

There are tons of [**examples**](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/index.html#Fragment) that demonstrate how to use `Fragment`s correctly on the Android developers site. I suggest you also take a look at the documentation [**here**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).

Finally, I'd just like to point out that it seems like a tabbed design would work great for your situation (i.e. filling the `ActionBar` with three tabs that allow quick navigation between `Fragment`s). Check out this [**sample code**](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentTabs.html) for more information.

Let me know if that helped! If not, leave a comment and I can clarify.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for all the information. I have done the exact same way you suggested(managing fragments from activity). But I have a button say share... So I want to show the user a dialog with facebook and twitter option when clicked. I cant use action bar as its out of requirement/ design. and I have to stick to the design. can you please help on this

Comment: Have you considered using the event callback approach with a DialogFragment that can list the options you need? The Activity would listen for the DialogFragment callback which would then launch the appropriate Activity or Application (Facebook, Twitter, etc).

Comment: I am trying the same... Thank you Raj